# IE8 opacity activex problem

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

In my css file I have this:

```
#imageDes {    
opacity:.70;
filter: alpha(opacity=70);  
}
```

if I use this on html page and open it in IE8, I get an activex warning!
What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard warning when running these sites in the local security zone.  If you run the page locally, you'll get the warning.  If you run it from a server, in the internet zone, you won't get the warning (unless you've modified your security settings).

If you need to run the page in the local zone without the warning, you can modify IE's security settings.

See [How to use security zones in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174360).

Comment: Or add the ugly “Mark of the Web”: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, I run this page locally in my browser. I also getting this error when i try create and use JSON  class object, is it the same reason?

Comment: @bobince: I forgot about that.  Good one.

Comment: @mariki: it's probably because you're running your page in compatibility mode and not IE8 standards mode.  try adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE8"/>` to your `<head>` tag.

Comment: @mariki: what JSON object are you trying to use? Just the native `JSON.parse`, or some kind of third-party library that might be trying to create an `XMLHttpRequest` of some sort? Anyhow, you'll need to fix your permissions problem by (a) adding mark-of-the-web to the page (take care to use a CRLF Windows line ending after the Mark or stupid IE won't accept it); (b) ticking the “Allow active content to run in files on My Computer” option (in Internet Options->Advanced); or (c) serving your files from a local web server instead of directly from the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

```
.class {    // for IE5-7
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.class {    // for IE8
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
}
```