# How can I check if cross-browser compatible?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

My humble question is if there is an online tool to check if your html/css & jQuery page is cross-browser compatible.  I have a simple fade-hover effecr with jquery and it works perfect in Chrome, but what about the other browsers?

Comment: Just load up each browser and test your stuff in each. An online tool would have no way of knowing if something's working or not - a lot of CSS/JS bugs do not throw errors, but still display completely wrong.

Comment: I doubt it, since if it IS different in other browsers, it will be a visual difference, which is pretty hard to programatically check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, let me stress the point made in one of the comments, that it is really important that you actually test your site for yourself in all browsers that you wish to support. A third party tool simply cannot give you the kind of assurance you need that your site will work flawlessly in any given browser.

Now to answer the question...

You haven't stated whether there are any particular browsers you are having trouble with. If your issue is with testing all the various versions of IE, you may want to look at [IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage), which installs all versions of IE into a single application, allowing you to test them all easily. It does have a tendency to crash, so it isn't suitable for use as a main browser, but it is certainly sufficient for testing.

If you only need screen shots of your site, [Browser Shots](http://browsershots.org/) is handy. You can use it to get a screen shot of your site running in virtually any browser ever released, in Windows, Linux or Mac. Not much use for testing dynamic content, but good for looking for any basic page layout issues.

If you're worried about specific browser features not being supported, you can look at [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/). This is a site which has browser support tables for over a hundred features. Very handy for helping you decide which features to use.

But since you specifically asked about jQuery, I should say that the whole point of jQuery is to minimise browser compatibility issues. The basic jQuery library is fully compatible with all browsers in current use, right back to IE6, so you really shouldn't have any issues with using it. The only thing I'd be careful about is fading, as IE8 and earlier don't deal with opacity very well. But even there it can work well if you do it right.

Third party jQuery plugins are a different story; they'll have their own set of browsers they support or not, and you'll need to check their individual web sites to confirm the details. But most of them should support the same set of browsers as the main jQuery library.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Well i have a little problem with IE8. When I test it in my browser it pops up the usual question. "allow blocked content?" About ActiveX controls or smthing like that. Is there anything to be done here?

Comment: @Andreas - this specific issue is due to the security settings in the browser, and running an ActiveX control (which fading uses in IE as the browser doesn't natively support this feature). See this question for more help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570966/ie8-opacity-activex-problem, and also numerous other questions here - it gets asked about quite a lot. Its good to be specific in your questions here; if you'd mentioned this issue in your question you would definitely have got a few more helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery but not HTML5 (which is still under development progress), then most highly your transition effects are cross-compatible. Because that's the reason behind js libraries. They are not dependent on browser so much and they do their own stuff. Otherwise jQuery doesn't have that much meaning to me it is not cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [SauceLabs](http://saucelabs.com/) is what you need. It loads a interactive visual of each browser for you to play with.

Answer (score 0):

[Browsercam](http://browsercam.com), but it will require you to check each browser manually.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.modern.ie/

[Modern.ie](http://www.modern.ie) will run tests for you and give you advice on how to fix the issue with valid html/css.
No installation needed.
They can also give you screenshots of your site on various devices.

> This tool detects common coding practices that may cause
>   compatibility problems or prevent your users from getting the best
>   possible experience on a webpage. Whenever possible we suggest a fix
>   or enhancement with web standards like HTML5 & CSS3 (or a graceful
>   fallback). It's not a complete checklist for coding the modern web –
>   just a starting point so you can spend less time testing for IE and
>   more time building what matters on the web.