# Should I do cross-browser testing if I am using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, testing, cross-browser

We are a small team of developers building a javascript application.

If we weren't using jQuery, we'd want to spend a lot of time making sure the code is cross-browser compatible, and we would run unit tests on all the platforms we supported. This is time-consuming, and adds to our workflow, or takes time to set up.

But, we do use jQuery. Do we still really need to do all that cross-browser testing?

I'm looking for some arguments for and against doing extensive cross-browser testing (i.e., using TestSwarm or something similar) if we already use jQuery -- a library that basically eliminates cross-browser issues.

Thoughts?

Comment: jQuery abstracts away a lot of cross browser inconsistencies, but it's still possible to write JavaScript that behaves differently on different browsers. I'd still recommend testing across browsers. Automate your testing and get in the habit of writing unit tests.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/7799171/1862502

Comment: Also have a read of http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=2222

Comment: Certain bugs in your code might be ignored in one browser, but surface in another. JQuery can't solve all that.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery runs on all major browsers, but it always depends on the implementation and anything may go wrong, so it is always a good practice to test it across browsers.

Doing this you will be safer. 99% of the code will work correct but there is still a risk involved for 1% of the code and that 1% may creep critical bugs.

Answer (score 1):

> But, we do use jQuery. Do we still really need to do all that cross-browser testing?

Yes

> I'm looking for some arguments for <s>and against</s> doing extensive cross-browser testing

- Because jQuery might have quirks you might not know about, unless you are really updated with their builds, bugs and fixes.
- jQuery might not have patched all differences.

  As far as I know, there was this difference in the older versions because IE did not support changing the type of the input when the element was already created:

  ```
  //IE:
  $('<input type="text"/>');

  //Other browsers:
  $('<input/>',{
    type : 'text'
  });
  ```
- jQuery does not patch everything.

  This argument holds true as to why [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is [patched](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), but not [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). [A bug report was created for this](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1886), but most of the responders replied that `reduce` isn't required internally thus it was omitted.
- jQuery, like other software, has bugs too
- Because there might be some newer JS API that your team members might consider stable when they aren't. An example is [`querySelectorAll`](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) which works quite well already, supported in many browsers, but has quirks [which are different from what you'd expect](http://blog.javascriptroom.com/2013/02/18/queryselector-quirks/).
- Just because you use a great CSS framework doesn't mean all layout problems have been solved. You still even do UI testing to make sure everything looks the same. *Same logic should go for all languages, even JS.*

Answer (score 0):

How extensively you test depends entirely on your application. It’s a bit of a “How long is a piece of string?” question.

I would say that with jQuery specifically, I’ve encountered bugs in IE 8 and older, often due to invalid HTML, that haven’t presented in other browsers.

And, as @kinakuta’s comment pointed out, jQuery doesn’t cover every browser JavaScript API, or replace the language itself. I’d imagine it’s unlikely that every significant line of JavaScript you write in your application will be jQuery.